# Equals Method False For the same objects

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();

        System.out.println(dog2.equals(dog1));

    }

    public static class Dog{

    }
}
```

*The objects are the same, but equals method says its false. Why? Is it not true? Class is empty. Thanks in advance*

Comment: Perhaps you should read the Javadoc of `equals` method.

Comment: They are not the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to see the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Because you have not overridden the `.equals(Object)` method and provided a looser equivalence test, the super-class (i.e., the Object class) version of `.equals(...)` is called. Because `dog1` and `dog2` refer to different objects occupying different memory space, by default, they are not equivalent. You must supply your own equivalence test to overcome this.

Comment: But why does it return true? 
 public static void main(String[] args) {    
//        init();
//        System.out.println(Staticvar.count);
//        Dog dog = new Dog();
//        System.out.println();
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("1");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("1");
        
        System.out.println(dog1.name.equals(dog2.name));

    }
    
    public static class Dog{
        
        private String name;
        
        public Dog(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    
}

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov, I would venture to guess that because you are providing object-data in that case, your compiler or IDE is automatically generating a `.equals(...)` method, which in turn is relying on the `.equals(...)` method of the `String` class. I could be mistaken on that, but that seems like the only plausible explanation, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override the `equals` method of your `Dog` class, it falls back on the one from the `Object` class, that compares object's addresses. You have two instances of `Dog`, so two different addresses, so they're not equal.

Comment: But "==" for addresses and equals for object's data. I cant understand

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov, by default, because the Super Class `Object` does not know your object data, it performs the most discriminatory test; i.e., it falls back to basically doing a `==` comparison. The only reason things like Strings and other built-in classes can compare object data with `.equals(...)` is because they provide override methods, within which code custom to that object type performs the equivalence test on the object data.

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov As SpencerD said, the default comportment of `equals` is the same as `==`. You should look at the `equals` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) on the Object equals method.  These objects are not the same by default behavior of the method; you would need to override it to have it return true.

Answer (score 0):

The class Dog does not override the default equals method so the default will apply (which is basically ==) and as dog1 and dog2 are two separate instances of Dog this will be false.

If you want to be able to discriminate in a different way, you should override the equals method and put your comparison logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you use **new** keyword while initializing, it means new instance. And two different object instances can be equal or not, depending upon equal definition of your class. The default **equals** method definition compares memory addresses, which would be different in this case.